# Is size inherent in the meanings of "plant" and "factory"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, nuance

I always had the impression that a *plant* was bigger than a *factory* and that a plant might contain several factories, but we wouldn't say that a factory contains several plants.

According to oxforddictionaries.com,

- > [*plant*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/plant?region=us&q=plant): a place where an industrial or manufacturing process takes place
  > *the company has 30 plants in Mexico*
- > [*factory*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/factory?region=us&q=factory): a building or group of buildings where goods are manufactured or assembled chiefly by machine

Not very specific.
Disregarding adjectives like "small plant" and "large factory," just looking at the words *plant* and *factory*, is one bigger than the other to the average native English speaker?

Comment: You mean, like _ship_ and _boat_...? After reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory), it seems like _plant_ might be bigger - but I had to look that up to form an opinion.

Comment: Where both *factory* and *plant* are used, it seems *plant* has connotations of a functional unit, while *factory* refers to the larger physical structure -- a *factory* may have several *plants* each for a specific purpose, never the other way around. We say the factory has an acetic acid plant among others. Construction terminology also follows a similar differentiation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) says this:

"plant (noun) 2 a : the land, buildings, machinery, apparatus, and fixtures employed in carrying on a trade or an industrial business; b : a factory or workshop for the manufacture of a particular product; also : power plant; c : **the total facilities available for production or service**; d : the buildings and other physical equipment of an institution"

"factory (noun) 2 a : a building or **set of buildings** with facilities for manufacturing"

There's no difference between them in my dialect. One word's shorter than the other's all that I can see. It's probably a matter of regional dialect and local (what they say at work, *plant* or *factory*) parlance.

However, one wouldn't call a *power plant* a *power factory*.

Comment: I find it interesting that "plant" includes the property outside and the machinery inside, while "factory" seems to be referring more to the buildings themselves.  That said, I agree with you: the difference in negligible - particularly once you're on the plant (factory) floor.

Comment: @J.R.: If one looks at the origin of the word, a factory is where factors lived and worked. It was usually a well-armed fort and included all the land as well as the buildings and machinery, especially when those factors were the Portuguese, the Dutch, the Spanish, and the British in Africa, Oceania, and Asia during the heyday of the spice trade. The online Etymological Dictionary says: "plant: _Sense of building 'planted' or begun for an industrial process first attested 1789_" & "factory: _Sense of 'building for making goods' first attested 1610s_". Both originally meant _a building_.

Answer (score 4):

Since

- `Factory` is the older term, and deals with the assembly of things, and
- `Plant` is a word that arose (in its modern usage) for *chemical refineries* and the like

you *could* consider a `Plant` more complex compared than a factory, if for no other reason than the added complexity of the refinery / reaction process(es) involved.

In fact, consider that smelting facilities are generally called a `plant` despite also involving factory-line types of post-process handling.

Also, I'd ponder that `plant` arose from `plantation` - which is more complex (in operations) than a factory.